# Celery beat reports ImproperlyConfigured for settings.DATABASES but database working fine

Tags: django, celery, django-celery

I want to run a task periodically in **Django** using **Celery** (**Celery beat**) in my development environment.

**apps/core/tasks.py**

```
from celery import task

@task()
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```

**settings.py** (only relevant parts)

```
import djcelery
from celery.schedules import crontab
from apps.startups.tasks import add

DATABASES = {
   'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': 'development.db',
    }
}

djcelery.setup_loader()
CELERY_IMPORTS = ("apps.core.tasks",)
BROKER_URL = 'amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672/'
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'add-every-day': {
        'task': 'apps.core.tasks.add',
        'schedule': crontab(hour=11, minute=43),
        'args': (16, 16),
    },
}
```

I then start the celery beat worker by running `python manage.py celery worker --beat`.

Then on `11:43` the celery process reports the following to me:

```
[2013-08-27 11:43:00,216: WARNING/PoolWorker-5]
/home/username/.virtualenvs/myproject/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/task/trace.py:341: RuntimeWarning:   
Exception raised outside body: ImproperlyConfigured(  
'settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value. Check settings documentation for more details.',)
```

That's strange since I've supplied my `'ENGINE'` value for in the `DATABASES` setting and I've never had any problems with my database in my project. Any clues why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was caused by this line: `from apps.core.tasks import add`. After removing it Celery worked as documented.

The line `CELERY_IMPORTS = ("apps.core.tasks",)` was not necessary. At least I didn't notice any difference without it.